# HTTP github Gem reference fails in Jenkins build

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, github, jenkins, bundler

I have a private ruby gem hosted in github that I have configured in my Gemfile to pull over https.

The line looks something like this:

```
gem 'gemname', :git => 'https://USERNAME:PASSWORD@github.com/Organizartion/gemname.git', :branch => 'develop'
```

The reason for the embedded username/password is that we are deploying to Heroku and Heroku doesn't allow user agent forwarding, so we have to pull the gem over HTTPS and we have to pass the un/pw in the request.

This works great deploying to heroku, but when I run my jenkins build i get this error.

```
Fetching https://USERNAME:PASSWORD@github.com/OrganizationName/gemname.git
fatal: https://USERNAME:PASSWORD@github.com/OrganizationName/gemname.git/info/refs download error - The requested URL returned error: 403
[31mGit error: command `git clone 'https://USERNAME:PASSWORD@github.com/OrganizationName/gemname.git' "/var/jenkins/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@gemset/cache/bundler/git/gemname-cbda297ed261fcb09cf9d2c19ff525a89feb4294" --bare --no-hardlinks` in directory /var/jenkins/workspace/ProjectDevelopment has failed.[0m
```

Has anyone has this problem before?

Comment: Which version of Jenkins are you running. There was a bug in versions prior to 1.1.6 with passwords in https:// username:password type of clone (see https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-3807 )

Comment: 1.431 so that's probably not it but there is an update so i'll try that anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can clone the repo as read-only from github without the requirement of a username and password.  I think this would be a better method unless you use github for a private repository.  You can also checkout public repos as readonly under HTTPS if thats any help.  In any case if you need write permissions you can easily change the .git config of the checkout to point to the read/write repo later.

Comment: ya unfortunately it is a private repo hence the un/pw requirement.